# Click event or item selection on dynamically loaded menu and submenu in android

Tags: android, menuitem

I am trying to implement click/item selection on dynamically loaded menu item and submenu item from server in android. But how should I find out or define the item id that has been loaded from server?

I am adding new menu and submenu from server this way ...

```
private class HttpAsyncTaskCheckAsset extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            return GET(urls[0]);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            Menu m = navigationView.getMenu();
            SubMenu topChannelMenu = m.addSubMenu("Assets");

            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray jsonAssets = jsonobject.getJSONArray("assets");
                    for(int j = 0; j < jsonAssets.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject jsonInnerObject = jsonAssets.getJSONObject(j);
                        String deviceName = jsonInnerObject.getString("name");
                        topChannelMenu.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_share);
                        topChannelMenu.add(deviceName);
                        Log.d("ASEETS_NAME",deviceName);
                        JSONObject idObject = jsonInnerObject.getJSONObject("_id");
                        String oid = idObject.getString("$oid");
                        Log.d("ASEETS_NAME",oid);

                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            MenuItem mi = m.getItem(m.size()-1);
            mi.setTitle(mi.getTitle());
        }
    }
```

Is there any other new way to do the same thing? 
Here I could not find the item id which is essential to implement item selection option. How should I solve this issue?

Comment: put your complete code

Comment: @NiravRanpara I did nothing on the Acitivity class which implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener but called HttpAsyncTaskCheckAsset() in onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

For item_id, you may want to use:
public abstract MenuItem add (int groupId, int itemId, int order, int titleRes). Pls. refer to the menu documentation for details:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int, int, int, java.lang.CharSequence)